# Pandas - binning within date groupby

Tags: python, pandas, bin

My goal is to summarize data by size within years of my dataset. I am able to do these two tasks separately (e.g. summarize by year, or summarize by bin) but am having syntax trouble combining the two.

Below is how I can summarize my data by year:

```
size_summary = df_raw.groupby(['Year'])['Quantity'].describe()
```

Below is how I create my bins

```
mult = 1
bins = [5*mult, 10*mult, 25*mult, 50*mult, 100*mult]
groups = df_raw.groupby(pd.cut(df_raw['Quantity'], bins))
```

When I try to combine the two in the below, I get an error message. Does anyone know how to combine this to reach my goal? Thank you for your help.

```
groups.groupby(['Year'])['Quantity'].describe()
```

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

EDIT: Adding sample data as requested, below.

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Year': [2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014],
    'Quantity': [2.0, 3.0, 78.8, 65.7, 70.0, 61.9, 83.9, 39.7, 44.1, 14.5, 35.3, 82.2, 13.9, 66.6, 65.8, 94.8, 50.8, 17.1, 9.9, 51.1, 62.9, 63.0, 13.5, 37.6, 1.5, 70.7, 23.3, 28.1, 21.9, 60.7, 1.1, 67.2, 0.4, 81.4, 86.7, 36.2, 45.2, 50.4, 43.3]
})
```

Desired output is in the format below - apologies for the screenshot. [image]

Comment: Please post a sample dataset and desired output.

Comment: As requested, please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `pivot_table`, you can group by the bins and year, and then reshape your data via `unstack`:

```
# first group by bins, then by year
groups = df_raw.groupby([pd.cut(df_raw['Quantity'], bins), 'Year'])

# compute group size, pivot into the shape you want
counts = groups.size().unstack(fill_value=0)
counts
```

```
Year       2012  2013  2014
Quantity                   
(5, 10]       0     1     0
(10, 25]      2     3     1
(25, 50]      3     2     3
(50, 100]     7     7     5
```

This is approximately 2.5x faster than `pivot_table` on the sample data you provided.

---

To split the categorical interval index into a `MultiIndex`, use something like

```
def interval_to_tuple(interval):
    return interval.left, interval.right

counts.set_index(
    counts.index.astype(object).map(interval_to_tuple).rename(['Lower', 'Upper']))
```

```
Year         2012  2013  2014
Lower Upper                  
5     10        0     1     0
10    25        2     3     1
25    50        3     2     3
50    100       7     7     5
```

You should be able to export this result into Excel without issues.

Comment: Do you know how to export it properly to excel? The interval index is giving it trouble

Comment: @Z_D, please see the edit. The idea is to split the categorical interval index into columns (or index levels, as I have done). It's not pretty, and there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You are really close. Please try this one:

```
mult = 1
bins = [0, 5*mult, 10*mult, 25*mult, 50*mult, 100*mult]
df_raw['bin'] = pd.cut(df_raw['Quantity'], bins)
df_raw.pivot_table(index = 'bin', columns = 'Year', aggfunc = 'count')
```